# How can i get Element Value in Json payload with out Square brackets around element value?

Tags: json, xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using a payload mediator in the workflow to Update my JSON payload. I have successfully updated the payload with incoming request values and return output in JSON only. But in my JSON response payload after payload mediator, I am getting [ Value ] for the JSON element against which I have updated values.

I did not want my JSON element value enclosed within [] braces. I want a simple output like **element: "Value"**.

Below is my JSON Response I receive after using the Payload mediator. Please guide me on how can I achieve the required output.

```
{
   "FIXML": {
      "Header": {
         "RequestHeader": {
            "MessageKey": {
               "RequestUUID": [
                  "FEBA_1553756445880"
               ],
               "ServiceRequestId": "executeFinacleScript",
               "ServiceRequestVersion": "10.2",
               "ChannelId": "COR"
            },
            "RequestMessageInfo": {
               "BankId": [
                  "04"
               ],
               "TimeZone": "GMT+05:00",
               "EntityId": "",
               "EntityType": "",
               "ArmCorrelationId": "",
               "MessageDateTime": 2020-03-03T16: 59: 10.000
            },
            "Security": {
               "Token": {
                  "PasswordToken": {
                     "UserId": "11111",
                     "Password": ""
                  }
               },
               "FICertToken": "",
               "RealUserLoginSessionId": "",
               "RealUser": "",
               "RealUserPwd": "",
               "SSOTransferToken": ""
            }
         }
      },
      "Body": {
         "executeFinacleScriptRequest": {
            "ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO": {
               "requestId": [
                  "validateAcct.scr"
               ]
            },
            "executeFinacleScript_CustomData": {
               "ACCT_NUM": [
                  "01122507578"
               ],
               "PHONE_NUM": [
                  "59887834"
               ],
               "NIC": [
                  "G2105493001653"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Conversion of Above JSON into XML as below.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FIXML>
   <Body>
      <executeFinacleScriptRequest>
         <ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO>
            <requestId>
               <element>validateAcct.scr</element>
            </requestId>
         </ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO>
         <executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
            <ACCT_NUM>
               <element>01122507578</element>
            </ACCT_NUM>
            <NIC>
               <element>G2105493001653</element>
            </NIC>
            <PHONE_NUM>
               <element>59887834</element>
            </PHONE_NUM>
         </executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
      </executeFinacleScriptRequest>
   </Body>
   <Header>
      <RequestHeader>
         <MessageKey>
            <ChannelId>COR</ChannelId>
            <RequestUUID>
               <element>FEBA_1553756445880</element>
            </RequestUUID>
            <ServiceRequestId>executeFinacleScript</ServiceRequestId>
            <ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion>
         </MessageKey>
         <RequestMessageInfo>
            <ArmCorrelationId />
            <BankId>
               <element>04</element>
            </BankId>
            <EntityId />
            <EntityType />
            <MessageDateTime>2020-03-03T18:31:48.000</MessageDateTime>
            <TimeZone>GMT+05:00</TimeZone>
         </RequestMessageInfo>
         <Security>
            <FICertToken />
            <RealUser />
            <RealUserLoginSessionId />
            <RealUserPwd />
            <SSOTransferToken />
            <Token>
               <PasswordToken>
                  <Password />
                  <UserId>11111</UserId>
               </PasswordToken>
            </Token>
         </Security>
      </RequestHeader>
   </Header>
</FIXML>
```

**Both JSON and XML files are used as Input and Output to Data mapper. But After data when I logged the message I get empty XML as below.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <FIXML>
         <Body>
            <executeFinacleScriptRequest>
               <ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO>
                  <requestId>
                     <element />
                  </requestId>
               </ExecuteFinacleScriptInputVO>
               <executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
                  <ACCT_NUM>
                     <element />
                  </ACCT_NUM>
                  <NIC>
                     <element />
                  </NIC>
                  <PHONE_NUM>
                     <element />
                  </PHONE_NUM>
               </executeFinacleScript_CustomData>
            </executeFinacleScriptRequest>
         </Body>
         <Header>
            <RequestHeader>
               <MessageKey>
                  <ChannelId />
                  <RequestUUID>
                     <element />
                  </RequestUUID>
                  <ServiceRequestId />
                  <ServiceRequestVersion />
               </MessageKey>
               <RequestMessageInfo>
                  <ArmCorrelationId />
                  <BankId>
                     <element />
                  </BankId>
                  <EntityId />
                  <EntityType />
                  <MessageDateTime />
                  <TimeZone />
               </RequestMessageInfo>
               <Security>
                  <FICertToken />
                  <RealUser />
                  <RealUserLoginSessionId />
                  <RealUserPwd />
                  <SSOTransferToken />
                  <Token>
                     <PasswordToken>
                        <Password />
                        <UserId />
                     </PasswordToken>
                  </Token>
               </Security>
            </RequestHeader>
         </Header>
      </FIXML>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Please Guide me here. How this conversion is properly done.**

Comment: What is the JSONPath or XPATH you are using to get the value?

Comment: json-eval($..body.AccountNumber)

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar ..Square bracket is coming and due to which i am not able to validate the actual value. My Expression {  $...DrAcct.AcctId}      MyOutPut:-  [
  "01022509732"
]